# How to render different view from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sort of noob-rails question ;):

I've got 2 actions in my controller - *index* and *own*.
In *index*, i'm listing all posts and *own* generates only logged users' posts. Controllers are pretty similar, but view is identical and I assume can be shared between this two controllers.

In the own controler I put something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :action => "index" }
  format.json { render json: @ads }
end
```

And added to routes:

```
match "/ads/own" => 'ads#own', :via => :get
```

Is there any better solution to do this?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112883/rails-3-1-different-views-for-one-model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def index
  ....
end

def own
  ....
  render :index    
end
```

Everything (all variables) will directly pass to the index view in own. If you want the :json component, then add:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
```

and put 'respond_with @posts' as the last item in each action.